# How to use the data retrieved from a servlet in the query statement present in a jsp file?

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am working on a project and I need to connect to a database from a jsp file. I have to use the data retrieved from a servlet in the where clause of the query.
I am unable to do so correctly. Please post sample codes if possible.

Part of my code is:

```
//to retrieve data in jsp from servlet
<%! String[] staffData;%>
<% retrievedInfo = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("filledInfo");%>
<% staffData = (String[]) retrievedInfo.get(0);%>

//After establishing connection:
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from EDUCATION where STAFF_NO= <% staffData[0] %>");
```

Please help me.
Please tell me where to make the changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't access a database from JSP, that's evil! Your view layer should know nothing about your model layer!

Comment: Plus this is a huge SQL injection risk.

Comment: The mistake is in your query. You are using "<% staffData[0]%>" instead of using "<%=staffData[0]%>". Moreover, the variable and the snipplet has to b written outside the quotes and not within it or they would be considered as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executeQuery needs to be in a scriptlet tag and you can refer to staffData[0] directly in the code

```
//to retrieve data in jsp from servlet
<%! String[] staffData;%>
<% retrievedInfo = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("filledInfo");%>
<% staffData = (String[]) retrievedInfo.get(0);%>

<%
//After establishing connection:
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from EDUCATION where STAFF_NO = ' "+staffData[0]+" '   ");


%>

<%
 //then iterate through the resultset...
 while(rs.next()) {
        out.print(rs.getObject(1).toString());
       //...etc..
      }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these ..

[Display table from database](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/DisplaytableinDatabase.htm)

[JSP Tags for SQL to connect to a database](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=614)

[Connecting to MySQL database and retrieving and displaying data in JSP page](http://knol.google.com/k/engineer-arif-naseem/connecting-to-mysql-database-and/18w7qu0jty11x/41#)

[Displaying Records from the Database with Java Servlets](http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001062501&page=1)

[MVC Example using Jsp, Servlets and java beans](http://javabuzzu.blogspot.com/2010/02/mvc-example-using-jsp-servlets-and-java.html)